# Heroku Grails buildpack: "Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified"

Tags: grails, heroku

I'm getting an "Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified" compiler error trying to push a Grails application to Heroku. I don't know of a way to enable more verbose logging during compilation but I'd be happy to provide more info.

```
506 ita-signup $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 31, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 2.74 KiB, done.
Total 21 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Grails app detected
-----> Grails 2.0.4 app detected
WARNING: The Grails buildpack is currently in Beta.
-----> Executing grails -Divy.default.ivy.user.dir=/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache compile --non-interactive
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
! Failed to build app
! Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Grails app
To git@heroku.com:XXX-3359.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:XXX-3359.git'
```

Comment: are you setting the heap size somewhere? can you show your Config and BuildConfig?

Comment: Can you file a support request with Heroku?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek: I'm not intentionally setting the heap size. "grails compile" works fine when run locally. The application config is https://github.com/backstop/ita-signup/tree/master/grails-app/conf

Comment: @James: yes, did that; 4 days ago with no response yet.

Answer (score 4):

Answer: I had set the [user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) feature. Using this to force valid heap settings worked:

```
$ heroku config:set JAVA_OPTS='-Xms384m -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops'
$ git push heroku master
...
(success)
```

Comment: If you are using a custom build pack like Play! don't forget to do the same with the SBT_OPTS variable. `heroku config:set SBT_OPTS='-Xms384m -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops'`